# What is the meaning of "The trial must not be countenanced" according to the conversation given down below?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Conversation from the movie named **SPIDER MAN**

GOBLIN: Spiderman is all but invincible. But, Parker, we can destroy him.

NORMAN: I can’t.

GOBLIN: **The trial must not be countenanced.** Parker must be educated.

NORMAN: What do I do?

GOBLIN: Instruct him in the matters of loss and pain. Make him suffer. Make him wish he were dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misheard. The line is:

> **Betrayal** must not be countenanced.

To countenance something means to admit as acceptable or possible.

In the previous line, the Goblin says "after everything you've done for Peter.... this is how he repays you?"

So "betrayal must not be countenanced" means that he will not accept, or stand for, what he perceives as a betrayal.